# 'Select/Deselect All' in semantic ui checkboxes

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I have seen a couple of other threads like this one, but I do not see why my code is not working.

I have a group of semantic UI checkboxes that should be checked when another checkbox called `All` is checked (similarly, all checkboxes should be unchecked when the `All` checkbox is unchecked).

```js
$('.custom').click(function() {
    $('input[name="other_checkboxes"]').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ui checkbox custom">
    <input id="all_box" type="checkbox" />
    <label>All</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="ui form grouped fields ss-checkbox-input" id="other_checkboxes">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="other_checkboxes" tabindex="0" value="A" />
        <label>A</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui checkbox  ">
        <input type="checkbox" name="other_checkboxes" tabindex="0" value="B" />
        <label>B</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a question but a do my work request

Comment: @elad BA If I was not turning around trying to see what is wrong with, what I assume is a fairly simple code for experienced people, I would not have created this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `this` is `div` not `input`. So instead of `this.checked` use `$(e.target).prop("checked")`

Try this one:

```js
$('.custom').click(function (e) {
    $('input[name="other_checkboxes"]').prop('checked', $(e.target).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <div>
        <div class="ui checkbox custom">
            <input id="all_box" type="checkbox" />
            <label>All</label>
        </div>

        <div class="ui form grouped fields ss-checkbox-input" id="other_checkboxes">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="other_checkboxes" tabindex="0" value="A" />
                    <label>A</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox  ">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="other_checkboxes" tabindex="0" value="B" />
                    <label>B</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @6po0222 because you forgot add jquery reference to your snippet. See my snippet work well

Answer (score 0):

A possible working solution.

```js
$("input[value='All']").change(function() {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui form grouped fields ss-checkbox-input" id="myCheckboxes">
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes" tabindex="0" value="All" />
          <label>All</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes" tabindex="0" value="A" />
          <label>A</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui checkbox  ">
          <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes" tabindex="0" value="B" />
          <label>B</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```